# How do I get this complex query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
company has_many customers
customer has_many messages
customer belongs_to company
company has_many messages
message belongs_to company
message belongs_to customer
```

A Message can be "sent" or "received" from the column "direction".

What I would like to find is the number of "conversations" per day where a conversation is defined as a customer sending at least one message and receiving at least one message (doesn't have to be in that order) in a single day, divided by the number of paying companies.

How can I get that in active record?

Comment: Is it possible a customer belongs to more than one company? In which case, you need the company `has_and_belongs_to_many customers`. And company `has_many messages through customer` and customer `has_many messages through company`.

Comment: a customer only belongs to one company

Comment: Is the `direction` column part of message? And if so, does that mean a single message has a redundant entry in both `company` (*e.g.*, sent) and `customer` (*e.g.*, received)? Since it's understood that a customer message must have been with the company, I would not attach messages separately to the company. I would use company `has_many messages through customer` instead of company `has_many messages`. That eliminates the redundancy.

Comment: direction is a column on message. but a message has_one customer and has_one company, so there isn't redundant recording

Comment: So then `direction` is always relative to the customer? Or relative to the company?

Comment: relative to the company. sent means the company sent the message, received means the company received the message

Comment: Seems this is going to be a GROUP BY / HAVING query. I would write out the straight SQL first, then build the ActiveRecord calls from that. I haven't worked it out completely, but it seems like for a given day you are ultimately counting customer rows, that have at least one "sent" message and one "received" message.

Comment: It's not clear to me how sent and received messages are paired for a conversation. If the customer sends one message, and the company sends two in reply, is that one conversation? Or is a conversation simply the pairing of any two sent and received couple of messages? Regardless, I still think that company `has_many messages through customer` might be the best structure.

Comment: @lurker a conversation is defined by an sent message and received message to/from a single customer on a single day by a single company

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Lets split the query into parts:

#### 1. You need to join the message table on itself on same company id.

```
Message.joins("LEFT JOIN messages AS m ON messages.company_id = m.company_id")
```

---

#### 2. Where customer is same for the two joined messages where messages is sent and m is received on the same day

```
.where("messages.direction = 'sent' AND m.direction = 'received' AND messages.customer_id = m.customer_id AND DATE(messages.created_at) = DATE(m.created_at)")
```

---

#### 3. You need to get the uniq messages sent and received by every customer everyday to/from the same company.

```
.select(" DISTINCT (messages.customer_id, messages.company_id, DATE(messages.created_at) )")
```

---

#### 4. Count Grouping by date created

```
.group('Date(messages.created_at)').count
```

---

#### Final Query:

```
Message.joins("LEFT JOIN messages AS m ON messages.company_id = m.company_id").where("messages.direction = 'sent' AND m.direction = 'received' AND messages.customer_id = m.customer_id AND DATE(messages.created_at) = DATE(m.created_at)").select(" DISTINCT (messages.customer_id, messages.company_id, DATE(messages.created_at) )").group('Date(messages.created_at)').count
```

Comment: yea gives me an error: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function count(integer, integer, date) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT messages.customer_id, messages.company...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: when i try without .count or just try the first piece of the query, it doesn't work

Comment: yes! that worked. last question - how would i group it by conversations/month instead of by day?

Comment: where would i put that EXTRACT?

Comment: Replace Part 4, with `.group('EXTRACT(month FROM messages.created_at)').count`

Comment: wonderful! ok sorry...how do i get month and year? i need to chart it and the chart doesn't know which year these months are for

Comment: For keeping the month linked to each year, use `.group("date_trunc('month', messages.created_at)").count` . its going to return the hash like this `{2014-11-01 00:00:00 UTC=> 99, 2014-12-01 00:00:00 UTC=>102 } `